# Java Struts Hibernate Web App on Eclipse

Tags: java, struts2

I am just getting started working on a **Java Struts Hibernate** based **Web App** on **Eclipse**.

I have installed **Eclipse** (Helios) **for Java EE developers** for linux.

While going through an Action Class SampleProjectAction.java, I find that that words **ActionForward, ActionMapping, ActionForm, HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, Exception** are **not highlighted** in **a different font/color**.

> ```
> public class SampleProjectAction extends Action {
>
>   public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
>                                  HttpServletRequest request, 
>                                    HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
> ```
>
> Does that mean Eclipse is **not able to recognize my Web App project**?
>
> Do I need to **install any additional plugins for Java, Struts, Hibernate** OR
>
> any **additonal jar files** are needed?

-

> **@hvgotcodes** All I have downloaded is Eclipse IDE for Java EE developers, nothing more. I have **not downloaded any jar files for Struts, Hibernate, etc.** and added to classpath. **How do I do that**?

Comment: you need to add the jars that compose each library, and possibly their dependencies as well, if you haven't all ready...

Comment: @hvgotcodes  Could you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: @user476216 -- so you downloaded the hibernate,struts, etc libraries right?  Did you add the jars to the classpath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax highlighting is only based on Java parsed syntax, it has nothing to do with recognized frameworks or jars. If the jar is missing, you'll have a compilation error because the compiler won't be able to find a class (example ActionMapping )

BTW: "Exception" is not a Struts class, it's from core Java.

BTW2: This is not Struts2, but Struts (1), they are totally different frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

man i like so much struts as a mvc framework, recently i post a struts 2 tutorial using spring framework, i uploaded the compressed web app (war) it includes all the depencies you need to run a struts 2 web app, i you want to get the app you should go to http://asotto.blogspot.com/2010/08/vistazo-spring-framework-un-ejemplo-del.html and download it. I hope it help you...